# How to create a ref to be used on a custom hook that creates the ref?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this simple hook:

```
export const useOverflow = (): {
  isOverflow: boolean;
  elementRef: React.RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>;
} => {
  const elementRef = createRef<HTMLParagraphElement>();
  const [isOverflow, setIsOverflow] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (elementRef.current) {
      setIsOverflow(
        elementRef.current.scrollWidth > elementRef.current.offsetWidth,
      );
    }
  }, [elementRef]);

  return { isOverflow, elementRef };
};
```

How do I test this with testing-library?

I have tried using a test component, but it falls into the issue that refs do not work with tests, so I would need to mock this ref somehow, but in my case it is not passed as a prop, but it is returned from the hook.

thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for anyone doing this for the first time:

Must spy on createRef method and mock the return value as needed.

```
const renderTest = () => renderHook(() => useOverflow());

describe('useOverflow', () => {
  it('should set overflow to true', () => {
    jest.spyOn(React, 'createRef').mockReturnValue({
      current: {
        scrollWidth: 5,
        offsetWidth: 2,
      },
    });
    const { result } = renderTest();
    expect(result.current.isOverflow).toBe(true);
  });
});
```